# Using Object Oriented Design with Ruby, how to show transfer of ownership?

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

Say we have the following classes: `Bakery`, `Equipment`, and `Batch`. `Bakery` is composed of `Equipment` like so:

```
class Bakery
  attr_accessor :equipment
end
```

`Equipment` looks like this:

```
class Equipment
  attr_accessor :name, :quantity
end
```

So to represent a bakery with two ovens we can do this:

```
ovens = Equipment.new
ovens.quantity = 2
bakery = Bakery.new
bakery.equipment = [ovens]
```

Now the `Batch` class represents one batch of baked goods. It is itself composed of a `Formula` with several `Step` objects. The `Formula` class contains the order of steps and timing information so that `Batch` knows when some equipment needs to be used. (I'm leaving out the `Formula` and `Batch` code for brevity. Full code is available [here](https://github.com/reedlaw/breadshop/blob/dfade9d8ed46e895bb1485eb7a51ec9e908e4989/backend/lib/entities/formula.rb) and [here](https://github.com/reedlaw/breadshop/blob/dfade9d8ed46e895bb1485eb7a51ec9e908e4989/backend/lib/entities/batch.rb).)

My question is how do I use OOD to temporarily transfer ownership of some equipment (say, 1 oven) from `bakery` to `batch`. `bakery` holds an instance of `Equipment` that represents two ovens. One of those ovens is going to be temporarily occupied by a `batch` process. Should I create a new instance of `Equipment` and pass it to the  `batch` while decrementing the `quantity` of `ovens`? Or should I not bother with the `quantity` attribute and simply create one instance of `Equipment` for each oven in the bakery? In that case I could simply pop the last oven off the `bakery.equipment` array and push it onto `batch.equipment` until `batch` is finished. One business logic requirement is to be able to query future availability of `bakery.equipment`. So there needs to be some distinction between the current state (i.e. how many ovens are occupied) and future states (i.e. how many ovens will be occupied at 9:00 PM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you incorrectly modeled your data. Your `Bakery` has not just equipment, but `available equipment` and `occupied equipment`. And `Batch` doesn't own anything, it asks Bakery to temporarily mark some equipment as occupied.

It can be modeled differently depending on your memory/performance/code simplicity requirements.

One example (not performance/memory wise, I suppose, but illustrative) is to have `Bakery` store available equipment pieces in a list, then pass `Bakery` to a new `Batch` instance to mark some slots (or increase usage counter on some items) as busy.

After `Batch` has marked all equipment in `Bakery` as busy according to its `Formula`, Bakery can then be analyzed.

Well, this is just an overall example and it's not very detailed. But then, I don't know the exact problem you are trying to solve ;)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer about the problem. The use case is: before starting a batch I want to be sure the necessary equipment will be available (i.e. not occupied). So the business logic should look at all of the currently running batches, available equipment, and occupied equipment and then determine if there will be enough available equipment to run a new batch. The logic needs to look ahead to the steps that require equipment because a batch can last, say, 15 hours and only use the oven for the last 2.

Comment: @ReedG.Law Well, that changes a lot. To me in this case Bakery is just an informational object about the capacity available. Batch should maintain timelines for that capacity inside itself by first copying capacity data from Bakery into itself and using it as an information only.